# How to press space key and then backspace key in a textarea: using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Do we have any way to press any keyboard key in textarea using JQuery?

**Usage in My Case**
There are many textareas have height of 100, set by default onload (some issue with JQuery Autosize used by some developer of which i have no access to change and i am not authorized to change). There is some text displayed in textarea. If it is less say 10 character only, the height of textarea will Remain same.

Now when end user click in Textarea and then press any button to edit, then at sudden textarea gets adjusted to normal height.

So i want jquery to fire key-press(space then backspace) on load on all textareas. Do we have any way to press any keyboard key in textarea using JQuery?

Comment: Try https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: @Pugazh: Is this keypress not an event like onKeyPress? Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As unable to trigger click so used following code to increase and decrease textarea:

```
autoHeight: function(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
```

},

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('textarea').each(function () {
            kontroll.autoHeight(this);
        }).on('input', function () {
            kontroll.autoHeight(this);
        });
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event. See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdgnbtw1/1/)

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    var d = $.Event('keydown');
    var e = $.Event('keydown');
    d.which = 32; // space
    e.which = 8; // backspace
    this.focus();
    this.trigger(d);
    this.trigger(e);
}
```

Manually trigger resize:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent('autosize:update', true, false);
    $(this).dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Destroying autoresize:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent('autosize:destroy', true, false);
    $(this).dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Happening nothing. Just a comment,Even if i remove trigger(e). I am unable to find space in textarea. Logically it should be there?

Comment: @fatherazrael It triggers an event so you can use that keydown value in your code. It doesn't actually print the key in the textbox.

Comment: @fatherazrael what about $('textarea').val('test'); Will this work for resizing the textarea's ?

Comment: Situatuion: Presently, If i enter some text in textarea and then save it. Same page appears with entered text in textarea. But size of textarea increases double. When i click in textarea and press key from keyboard. The Size automatically comes upto text. So need to trigger key press on textarea using JQuery. Above is nice example but it is not working still :(

Comment: @fatherazrael I added autoresize and autodestroy functions maybe you can try one of these.